# IF with multiple conditions in EXCEL

Tags: excel, if-statement

requirement: cell must be populated to the max of 15 chars.

- if text<15, add spaces to the max of 15
- if text>15, trim and display only the fist 15 chars

I used the below formula, where B1=15

=IF(LEN(A19)<$B$1,REPT(" ",$B$1-LEN(A19))&A19,TRIM(TEXTBEFORE(LEFT(A19,$B$1),"",-1)))

It seems to be working for most cases, except where the value in A19 has spaces>15 or spaces+text>15 or text+spaces>15.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 15 spaces to every cell and take first 15 characters:

```
=LEFT(A1&REPT(" ",B1),15)
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works! so much simpler formula and it solved my problem. Appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it worked. =LEFT(A1&REPT(" ",B1),B1) would be more universal

Comment: you're right, i'll probably use B1 instead of 15, need to apply the formula to different columns in the file, and the reference will be different for each.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=RIGHT(REPT(" ",$B$1)&A19,$B$1)
```

Comment: thank you Rory. I replaced TRIM with RIGHT(REPT(" ",$B$1)&A19,$B$1)), it displays the last 15 chars of the text, but i am looking to display the first 15 chars